# How can I get rid of MS Word 2019 security dialogs when updating word function fields via C#?

Tags: c#, security, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I have a word document (.docx) where I'm inserting URIs to images in field functions.
To update those fields in the document I'm using C# and the MS word interop functionalities.
When I update those fields (which is manually pressing F9 in Word I think) I get the following dialogue box which I have to confirm manually:

[image: Office security dialogue]

An excerpt of my code looks like the following:

```
w = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
w.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
w.ScreenUpdating = false;
...
oDoc.MailMerge.Application.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update();
```

The last line is the crucial one which triggers the security dialogue because if the images URIs. Everything works as intended when I confirm the dialogue. The images load correctly and there are no other pitfalls. How can I get rid of this security notice?

What I tried so far:

1. Updating my word installation and lower security threshholds (such as enabling macros and adding safe space location in the TrustCenter
2. As you can see I also tried to disable `DisplayAlerts` programmatically how ever it does have no impact it seems.

I understand that this is a valid security concern and that MS office tries to prohebit those actions. How ever is there any way I could get rid of the dialogue? Either via configurating my MS Word in such a way or programmatically disable the security policy (I doubt that this is possible)? I also have to confirm the security notice when I'm updating the fields manually via MS Word.

I also read about that I could sign my application which performs the field updates.
Would the signing in the end mean that I would get rid of the dialogue because the document and the application is trusted by MS Word/Office?

[Source for signing documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-sign-application-and-deployment-manifests?view=vs-2022)

Any advices or hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Word object model doesn't provide anything for that. You can manually change settings under `Privacy Options`, select or clear `Check Microsoft Office documents that are from or link to suspicious Web sites` check box. See [Enable or disable security alerts about links and files from suspicious websites](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/enable-or-disable-security-alerts-about-links-and-files-from-suspicious-websites-a1ac6ae9-5c4a-4eb3-b3f8-143336039bbe) for more information.
I believe all Word options are stored in the windows registry, so you could use any tool for monitoring changes such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/.

Also there was a bug in the product, see [How do I disable "Microsoft Word Security Notice" pop-up](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-disable-microsoft-word-security-notice/3714060c-bf5b-431e-a03f-6a339b72d4c5?auth=1) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. The link your provided how ever is only applicable for Office 2010 / 2013. I think the CheckBox you mentioned is not available anymore in newer Office versions.

Comment: There is no other way, I mean the Word object model.